# Exibição de campo DateTime em View sem parte de Horas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Com o código abaixo estou recuperando o DateTime com o tempo além da data, o que eu não gostaria.

```
cursos.Data = DateTime.Parse(collection["Data"]);
```

Tentei formatar usando o substring dentro do DateTime.Parse, mas não obtive sucesso.

Meu domínio

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime Data { get; set; }
```

No CMS do cliente no modo de edição, esta sendo exibido 30/08/2014 00:00:00, apesar de no banco estar com a data correta, ou seja, sem o horário

Comment: O que você quer dizer com: "com o tempo além da data", tente ser mais claro em sua pergunta, e dar mais detalhes de seu problema.

Comment: Tente usar isso: cursos.Data = DateTime.Parse(collection["Data"]).ToShortDateString();

Comment: Não entendi o motivo dos votos negativos. @DiegoZanardo tentei mas não obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse problema é bem comum quando há manipulação de `DateTime` em `Views`. A melhor maneira de resolver é usando o seguinte:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Data, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "meuCampoDate" })
```

Veja também:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833695(v=vs.118).aspx