# Views Index, Views de listagem mostram data no formato errado

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto ASP.Net MVC e as Views Index e as Views de listagem mostram a data no formato Ano/Mês/Dia, mas quero que mostrem no formato Dia/Mês/Ano.

O quê eu faço?

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao [pt.so]. Uma boa prática para iniciarmos uma discussão saudável é fazer o [tour], caso ainda não tenha feito, e ler o guia de [ask]. Comece seguindo estas recomendações, principalmente sabendo quais os tipos de perguntas deve fazer, como criar um exemplo mínimo que seja completo e verificável e até mesmo o que fazer quando alguém te responder.

Comment: Se puder poste o código?

Comment: @Html.Raw(Datetime.now().toString("dd/MM/yyyy")) ?

Comment: Possível duplicada: [Formatar data e hora e listar de acordo com a data atual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28675/18246)

Comment: Possível duplicada: [Exibição de campo DateTime em View sem parte de Horas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27407/18246)

Comment: Possível duplicada: [Formatação de exibição de Data DisplayFor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162550/18246)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possivelmente seu Windows está em inglês, o que faz a configuração de formatos de data estar no formato americano.

No arquivo `Web.config`, adicione o seguinte:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
    ...
    <globalization culture="pt-BR" enableClientBasedCulture="false" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
    ...
  </system.web>
  ...
</configuration>
```